# c++ printing object and constructor

Tags: c++, oop

Hello everyone I had a problem while running the following program in the last loop it only print three 0 without displaying any result I am not sure what is wrong with the program,perhaps it has something to do with the constructor, however when I write my getter method in the second last loop with setter method it display the correct result. any help will be appreciated.

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
#define EMPLOYEE_H_INCLUDED
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class Employee
{
   private:
    string name;
    int idnumber;
    string department;
    string position;

   public:
     Employee(string ,int ,string ,string);
     void setName(string );
     void setDepartment(string);
     void setPosition(string);
     void setIDNumber(int);

     string getName() const
     {
         return name;
     }
     string getDepartment() const
     {
         return department;
     }
     string getPosition() const
     {
         return position;
     }
     int getIDnumber() const
     {
         return idnumber;
     }
};

#include "Employee.h";
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
Employee::Employee(string name ,int IDNumber ,string department ,string position)
{
   name=name;
   idnumber=IDNumber;
   department=department;
   position=position;
}
void Employee::setDepartment(string Department)
{
   department=Department;
}
void Employee::setName(string Name)
{
    name=Name;
}
void Employee::setPosition(string Position)
{
    position=Position;
}
void Employee::setIDNumber(int Number)
{
    idnumber=Number;
}



  int main()
  {
    string name;
    int IDNumber;
    string department;
    string position;
    const int Item=3;

    Employee info1("  ",0,"  ","  ");
    Employee info2("  ",0,"  ","  ");
    Employee info3("  ",0,"  ","  ");
    Employee Info[Item]={info1,info2,info3};
  }
  for(Employee element:Info)
  {
      cout<<"please enter your name "<<endl;
      cin>>name;
      element.setName(name);
      cout<<element.getName()<<endl;
      cout<<"please enter your department "<<endl;
      cin>>department;
      element.setDepartment(department);
      cout<<element.getDepartment()<<endl;

      cout<<"please enter your position"<<endl;
      cin>>position;
      element.setPosition(position);
      cout<<element.getPosition()<<endl;

      cout<<"please enter your IDNumber"<<endl;
      cin>>IDNumber;
      element.setIDNumber(IDNumber);
      cout<<element.getIDnumber()<<endl;

  }
  for(Employee element:Info)
  {
    cout<<element.getName()<<setw(8)<<element.getDepartment()   
    cout<<setw(8)<<element.getPosition()<<setw(8)<<element.getIDnumber()<<endl;
  }
```

}

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger?

Comment: It looks to me like your loops are outside of your main method. I would check to see if rearranging your code would fix it. I'd be surprised if this even builds.

Comment: @MrEricSir That would be quite a challenge, since the code wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(Employee element:Info)
```

`element` is a copy of an element from `Info` array. You are busy filling this copy, then it gets discarded. Contents of `Info` remain unchanged, with empty strings all around.

Make it

```
for(Employee& element:Info)
```

Note the ampersand.